# How to properly write Doctrine 2 DQL queries?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

I have upgraded to Doctrine 2.2.2 now. I have managed to successfully connect my database to my application and was able to generate proxies and repositories. I have no problem with those generation. I am just confused with regards to using the DQL of doctrine 2.2.2.
The case is this: I currently have a repository class responsible for user registration, authentication, etc. I have managed to execute the DQL on it but I just felt weird about this stuff (in my repository class).

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT u FROM MyProject\\Entity\\AdminUsers u");
```

I tried also:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT u FROM AdminUsers u");
```

The last did not work but the first one works fine but it seems weird. Is it really the right way of executing DQL in doctrine 2? or am I missing something important.

NOTE: on the above declaration of this repository class is:

```
namespace MyProject\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository,
    MyProject\Entity\AdminUsers;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It almost is the right way to do it. If you would use single quotes `'`, you could just use a single backslash `\` instead of  a double backslash `\\`.

Doctrine cant find out (or it would be extremely expensive to do so) which classes you imported via `use` statements.

But you can use a typed repository which you retrieve from the entity manager via:

```
$repo  = $em->getRepository('MyDomain\Model\User');
$res = $repo->findSomeone();
```

And in the `findSomeone()` function you can do this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$dql = $qb->where('u.id = 1')->getDQL();

return $this->_em->createQuery($dql)->getSingleResult();
```

Meaning, the repository is already typed on your entity and knows which class to select from.

Some documentation:

- [Querying with doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)
- [Querybuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)
- [10 step get started guide](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/in-ten-quick-steps.html) (which covers the basics including repositories)